# Average with CSS "flex-direction"

Tags: html, css

I want the left `div` to act as a box so I can place the right `div` right in the middle.

```css
.navBar {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6rem;
  bottom: 6rem;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.navDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navTittle {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 2rem;
}

.navStart {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="navBar">
            <ul class="navLinks">
                <div class="navDiv">
                    <li class="navStart">
                        <div class="column">
                            <span class="navTittle">Home</span>
                            <span class="downLine">Welcome -</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">01 ------</div>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

[image]

How can I place the area I marked in red in the middle of the blue box? I'm giving the div `flex-direction: column;` but the red area is just placed in the middle of the text "Home". i.e. it ignores `column`

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://imgur.com/a/S13xKWs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code is correct,

The text in red border is placed right exactly in the vertical centre of the .column, but since the navTittle has bigger font and it is taking most of the height of the column, (say 70%), you are getting a feeling that the text in right box is not on the middle of .column.

I have given borders in the below snippet for a better understanding.

#green: the container.
#blue: Left part.
#red: Right part.

So as you can observe, the red text is in the vertical middle of the wrapper as well as the text on the left.

If you are looking to arrange the text to below, you can use `margin-top` to arrange it.

```css
.navBar {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6rem;
  bottom: 6rem;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.navDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navTittle {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 2rem;
}

.navStart {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section class="navBar">
            <ul class="navLinks">
                <div class="navDiv">
                    <li class="navStart">
                        <div class="column">
                            <span class="navTittle">Home</span>
                            <span class="downLine">Welcome -</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">01 ------</div>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

Comment: `margin` needs measurement (this makes the code poor quality). As the font gets bigger, upper `padding` becomes more than lower `padding`, can we prevent this?

Comment: No, there is no padding affected on any of the elements in border, its just the font-size that is causing this issue. Upper font-size is larger, that's it. As you suggester, yes margin would require measurement, but if the text is a static one, I wouldn't hesitate doing that.